# Getting "Could not build wheels for numpy, which is a required to install pyproject.toml-based projects" When Numpy is already installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, package-managers

I'm trying to install opencv-python to do some machine learning/image-based projects, however *every* time I try to install opencv-python through pip it gives this output about halfway through:

```
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've tried doing what it says before this, (the error is from a raised `SystemError`, saying you need to install python-dev, however I cannot figure that out.

Next, I tried installing it through Homebrew, however that was going to make me install Xcode.

Finally, I tried installing it using `conda`, however I think I botched the `conda` install somehow, as it never worked either (`conda` was never shown as a bash command).

I'm not sure why this is a problem, I already have NumPy installed on my machine, and have used it before.

I've tried several other Stack Overflow threads, none of them being successful.